# ADDING TIME FROM SUBQUERIES MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
FLIGHTS 
FNO   Departs   Arrives    Price
111   10:00:00  11:30:00   5000    
222   13:30:00  18:00:00   6000    
333   20:00:00  22:30:00   3000    
444   22:45:00  23:30:00   1000
```

Requirement:

> I want to calculate the TOTAL_TIME of Travel using only flights 111,222,333.

I tried TIMEDIFF and ADDTIME, but I am not able to add results of subquery and get in TIME format.

Comment: Is it oracle or mysql? And your flight numbers do not match the table data

Comment: Hi, Its MYSQL. Values are stored using TIME datatype. A flight Departs at 10AM and Arrives at destination at 11:30AM.

Comment: Have you tried: `select sum(TIMEDIFF(arrives, departs))
from flights
where fno in (111,222,333)`?

Comment: BTW this won't work anymore if the time is on another day: departs at 23:00 and arrives at 05:00 for instance. You need also a date

Comment: Ya I tried to sum it up. But its not giving the required result. Yes, Later I realized that Date also should have been included :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Arrives, Departs)))) Total_Duration
FROM FLIGHTS
WHERE FNO IN (111,222,333);
```

See [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b18f96/17).

Comment: I want to add all the times and display the total travel time, which is logically 08:30:00.

Comment: When we are adding difference of 01:00:00 to 03:00:00 and 12:00:50 to 23:55:00 then it gives wrong output